# AutoPtr in C++/CLI mixed mode

Tags: c++-cli, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, cautoptr

I have a C++/CLI wrapper around native .lib and .h files.  I use the AutoPtr class pretty extensively in the wrapper class to manage the unmanaged objects I create for wrapping.  I have hit a roadblock with the copy constructor/assignment operator.

Using the AutoPtr class from Mr. Kerr: http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/03/26/AutoPtr.aspx

He suggests the following(in the comments) to recreate the behavior of the assignment operator:

```
SomeManagedClass->NativePointer.Reset(new NativeType);
```

Which I believe is true.  But when I compile my code:

```
ByteMessageWrap (const ByteMessageWrap% rhs)
{
     AutoPtr<ByteMessage> m_NativeByteMessage(rhs.m_NativeByteMessage.GetPointer());
};

ByteMessageWrap% operator=(const ByteMessageWrap% rhs)
{
     //SomeManagedClass->NativePointer.Reset(new NativeType);
     if (this == %rhs) // prevent assignment to self
        return *this;

     this->m_NativeByteMessage.Reset(rhs.m_NativeByteMessage.GetPointer());
     return *this;
};
```

-- I get the following errors:

> error C2662:
>   'WrapTest::AutoPtr::GetPointer' :
>   cannot convert 'this' pointer from
>   'const WrapTest::AutoPtr' to
>   'WrapTest::AutoPtr %'

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

---

For further background on the answer, I removed the "const" keyword from the signature.  I know that is not smiled upon in terms of code correctness for a copy ctor, but the CLR doesn't like it at all -- sort of belies the CLR at its core with memory management.

I wonder if it's possible to leave the const in the signature and then use GCHandle or pin_ptr to make sure memory doesn't move on you while performing the copy?

Comment: For clarity, I get that error on both lines of code calling the GetPointer() method.

Comment: Hmm... I'm still thinking about this. What behavior do you really want? Do you want a ByteMessage's native byte message to be discarded or cloned when a ByteMessage is copied?

Maybe ByteMessage shouldn't have a copy constructor, since it's a managed class -- how about ICloneable instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Kenny Kerr's AutoPtr, it transfers ownership in its constructor -- essentially a "move" constructor rather than a copy constructor. This is analogous with std::auto_ptr.

If you really want to transfer ownership from rhs to this (i.e. leave rhs without it NativeByteMessage), you need to change your copy ctor into a move ctor.

Also, you need to use initialization syntax;

```
// warning - code below doesn't work
ByteMessageWrap (ByteMessageWrap% rhs)
    : m_NativeByteMessage(rhs.m_NativeByteMessage); // take ownership
{
}

ByteMessageWrap% operator=(ByteMessageWrap% rhs)
{
     //SomeManagedClass->NativePointer.Reset(new NativeType);
     if (this == %rhs) // prevent assignment to self
        return *this;

     m_NativeByteMessage.Reset(rhs.m_NativeByteMessage.Release());
     return *this;
}
```